# Several list comprehensions - one after each other

Tags: python, for-loop, list-comprehension

I have written some code, and to try and grasp the concept of list comprehensions, I am trying to convert some of the code into list comprehensions.

I have a nested for loop:

```
with (Input) as searchfile:
    for line in searchfile:
        if '*' in line:
            ID = line[2:13]
            IDstr = ID.strip()
            print IDstr
            hit = line
            for i, x in enumerate(hit):
                    if x=='*':
                      position.append(i)
                      print position
```

I have made the first part of the code into a list comprehension as such:

```
ID = [line[2:13].strip() for line in Input if '*' in line]
print ID
```

This works fine. I have tried to do some of the next, but it is not working as intended. How do I make several list comprehensions after each other. The "Hit = …"-part below works fine, if it is the first list comprehension, but not if it is the second. The same with the above - it seems to work only, if it is the first. Why is this?

```
Hit = [line for line in Input if '*' in line]
print Hit

Positions = [(i, x) for i, x in enumerate(Hit) if x == '*']
print Positions
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it seems to work only, if it is the first. Why is this?

This is because `file` objects -- `input` in your case -- are iterators, i.e. they are exhausted once you iterated them once. In your for loop this is not a problem, because you are iterating the file just once for both `ID` and `position`. If you want to use two list comprehensions like this, you either have to open the file anew for the second one, or read the lines from the file into a list, and use that list in the list comprehensions.

Also note that your `positions` list comprehension is wrong, as it enumerates the `Hit` list, and not each of the elements *in* the list, as was the case in your loop.

You could try like this (not tested):

```
# first, get the lines with '*' just once, cached as a list
star_lines = [line for line in input if '*' in line]
# now get the IDs using those cached lines
ids = [line[2:13].strip() for line in star_lines]
# for the positions we need a nested list comprehension
positions = [i for line in star_lines for i, x in enumerate(line) if x == '*']
```

That nested list comprehension is about equivalent to this nested loop:

```
positions = []
for line in star_lines:
    for i, x in enumerate(line):
        if x == '*':
            posiitons.append(i)
```

Basically, you just "flatten" that block of code and put the thing to be appended to the front.

Comment: That makes perfect sense, @tobias_k. Your answer has been tested, and it works! Thank you.

Comment: Could you give me a short explanantion of how the nested list comprehension in the above works?